# jQuery merging/filter selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtering

I want to merge a selector split by another selector.
My actual selector looks like `$('.JS_toggle-submenu')`

```
<li class=​"JS_toggle-submenu" data-submenu=​"#submenu-l2-foo">​…​</li>​
<h2 class=​"JS_toggle-submenu" data-submenu=​"#submenu-l2-foo">​…​</h2>​
<p class=​"JS_toggle-submenu" data-submenu=​"#submenu-l3-bar">​…</p>​
<h3 class=​"JS_toggle-submenu" data-submenu=​"#submenu-l3-bar">​…</h3>​
```

And would like to filter it to the first of each data-submenu like
  `$('.JS_toggle-submenu').filter('[data=GROUPING]:first')`

```
<li class=​"JS_toggle-submenu" data-submenu=​"#submenu-l2-foo">​…​</li>​
<p class=​"JS_toggle-submenu" data-submenu=​"#submenu-l3-bar">​…</p>​
```

Of course, I'm not looking for a static solution.
I don't see an efficient way to do this, it seems I need to **loop** again but I would prefer to avoid, but maybe someone here have a magical solution?

**//EDIT:**
I need a IE7/8 compatibility, that's why I didn't choose the indexOf solution, but I omitted to explain in my original question.
I compared the both result here http://jsperf.com/filter-loop-or-regex same *Ops/sec*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter the IDs out based on an array of objects you'd found before. Something like:

```
// Array of IDs already found
var existing = [];
// Regex to pull the level number from the data attribute
var regexp = new RegExp("#submenu-l([0-9]+)-(.*?)", "i");
console.log($(".JS_toggle-submenu[data-submenu^='#submenu-l']").filter(function() {
    // Get the ID
    var id = regexp.exec($(this).data("submenu"))[1];
    // If we have already found a DOM element for this level, continue
    if(existing[id]) return false;
    // Otherwise add it to the existing found elements...
    existing[id] = true;
    // Allow it to pass through the filter
    return true;
}).get());
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ne40puve/)

Comment: I hope somebody gives a better solution though :)

Comment: Great! I'm trying to make a JSperf to compare with the other answer!

Comment: Don't forget to remove the `.get()` and `console.log` - they're just for debugging

Comment: http://jsperf.com/filter-loop-or-regex it's the same, but I prefer the regex version!

Answer (score 1):

Here's using a jquery each loop: http://jsfiddle.net/3y69usxv/

```
var submenus = [];
var firstMenus = [];

$('.JS_toggle-submenu').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    if (submenus.indexOf($this.data('submenu')) < 0) {
        submenus.push($this.data('submenu'));
        firstMenus.push($this);
    }
});

console.log(firstMenus);
```

Comment: I just needed to add a .map to make a selector, I prefer the other version (and I didn't said it, but I need IE7-8 compatibility) http://jsperf.com/filter-loop-or-regex